# Error key already exists appears only while executing function

Tags: postgresql, key, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

I have 2 tables, in one I create an element, in the other I save the details of said element in different languages.

The first table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.element
(
  idelement integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('element_idelement_seq'::regclass),
  image_location text,
  price numeric(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT element_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idelement)
)
```

the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.elementdetails
(
  idelement integer NOT NULL,
  title text,
  description text,
  notes text,
  language text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT elementdetails_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idelement, language)
)
```

I use a function to insert the new elements in plpgsql

```
IF _idelement = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO element (price) VALUES (0.0);
    SELECT lastval() INTO _idelement;
    EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO elementdetails(idelement, %I, language) VALUES (%L, %L, %L))', _fieldname, _idelement, _value, _language);
END IF;
```

But it raises an error saying the key constraints (idelement, language) already exists.

Simply copying the SQL appearing in the error message and executing it in another window would work with no issues and the problem appears only while within the pgsql function.

EDIT: I'll add that this worked until I noticed an issue where I let people insert the language iso both in uppercase or lowercase, so I forced the language to always be uppercase, since then I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

right after that statement I had another one

```
IF _idelement > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO elementdetails(idelement, %I, language) VALUES (%L, %L, %L))', _fieldname, _idelement, _value, _language);
END IF;
```

but I forgot to put it after an ELSE so both INSERTs were executed which raised the error.